# Android SQLite DatabaseHelper unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-database

I'm trying to use this `DBManager` as SQLite database helper. The problem is that it does creates the database but first throws this error. I'm not getting how to create the database without facing this error.

**Note :** There are similar questions but does not solve this problem. It does not throw write external storage permission exception.

Here's my database helper class :

```
 public class DBManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   private static final String TAG = DBManager.class.getSimpleName();

  // All Static variables
  // Database Version
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  // Database Name
  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "iap";

  // Login table name
  private static final String TABLE_STORIES = "stories";
  private ArrayList<Story> storiesList = new ArrayList<>();
  private Context mContext;

  public DBManager(Context context) {
     super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
     mContext = context;
  }

  // Creating Tables
  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     if(checkDataBase()){
        Log.d(TAG, "Database exists and readable");

     }else {

        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STORIES + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PIC + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EXTERNAL_LINK + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EXTERNAL_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PIC_CREDIT_LINK + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PIC_CREDIT_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DATE + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

        Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
     }

  }

  /**
   * Check if the database exist and can be read.
   *
   * @return true if it exists and can be read, false if it doesn't
   */
  private boolean checkDataBase() {
     SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
     try {
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        checkDB.close();
     } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return checkDB != null;
     /*File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
     return dbFile.exists();*/
  }

  // Upgrading database
  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
     // Drop older table if existed
     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_STORIES);

     // Create tables again
     onCreate(db);
  }
}
```

This is the log (**See the last line**):

```
04-13 16:07:12.918 10920-10920/news.inapic.app E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 32456 of [bda77dda96]
       04-13 16:07:12.918 10920-10920/news.inapic.app E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:32456: (2) open(//iap) - 
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database 'iap'.
       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:808)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:793)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
       at news.inapic.app.Helpers.DBManager.checkDataBase(DBManager.java:82)
       at news.inapic.app.Helpers.DBManager.onCreate(DBManager.java:53)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
       at news.inapic.app.Helpers.DBManager.getStories(DBManager.java:139)
       at news.inapic.app.Acitivity.MainActivity.setupViewPager(MainActivity.java:240)
       at news.inapic.app.Acitivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:209)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:808)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:793)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at news.inapic.app.Helpers.DBManager.checkDataBase(DBManager.java:82)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at news.inapic.app.Helpers.DBManager.onCreate(DBManager.java:53)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at news.inapic.app.Helpers.DBManager.getStories(DBManager.java:139)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at news.inapic.app.Acitivity.MainActivity.setupViewPager(MainActivity.java:240)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at news.inapic.app.Acitivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:209)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
       04-13 16:07:12.919 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
       04-13 16:07:12.920 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
       04-13 16:07:12.920 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
       04-13 16:07:12.920 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
       04-13 16:07:12.920 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
       04-13 16:07:12.920 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       04-13 16:07:12.920 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       04-13 16:07:12.920 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
       04-13 16:07:12.920 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       04-13 16:07:12.920 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
       04-13 16:07:12.920 10920-10920/news.inapic.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
       04-13 16:07:12.921 10920-10920/news.inapic.app D/DBManager: Database tables created
```

Comment: where is your DB_Path?

Comment: Just remove the `checkDatabase()` function. Why do you have it in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to check if the database exists in `onCreate()`. You can assume that :

- The database exists
- It is opened in read-write mode
- [`onConfigure()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onConfigure(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)) has been called
- You are in a transaction

Additionally, it is considered a good practice to use a single instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Answer (score 1):

You can make a static instance method to access database as singleton class pattern.

```
public static DBManager instance;

/** Get instance of current database.*/
public static DBManager getInstance(Context context){
 if(instace==null){
   instance= new DBManager(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
  return instace;
  }
```

And in on create you don't need to check that is a database is open or not.  it will gives you an error because you are trying to access database before it create. May this is helpful to you.